# Selenium Webdriver c# to iterate through elements

Tags: c#, selenium

I tried to get the elements under an `li` tag and perform a click operation on each `li`. I am only able to click on the first element; I cannot click on any of the rest.

My code is

```
IWebElement hover1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath ( "//*[@id='oe_menu']" ));
IList<IWebElement> subelements = hover1.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   subelements[i].Click();
   driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to go on in the slightest. What happens after the first click? What error do you get? Post that error along with it's *full* stack trace. Also, you are setting the `implicit wait` in each sequence within the loop. This is unnecessary and is only going to complicate things. Set it once and once only.

Comment: i am not getting error , click is made on the first element alone and then the driver quits and exists the firefox window , oki i ll try to remove that wait function

Comment: well ,even aftr removing the implicit wait its just clicking on the first element and then exists the window, i guess  its not able to get the proper element in a index manner since i found out 33 elements under <li> tag are present where i need only first 4 elements to be clicked and viewed.

Comment: @user3065782 Before performing action (Click event), in the same loop check if the first 4 "li" elements are the same u wanted to click.
May be Print their text or get some attribute and check.